# Get object name from ReferenceError

Tags: javascript

I'm curious if there is a way to get the name of the referenced object from a caught ReferenceError.
For example:

```
 try{
     foo;
 } catch(e){
     e.message; // "ReferenceError: foo is not defined"
 }
```

Is there another property holding "foo"? I'd like to create something like missing_method in ruby if it's possible. Except for variable access, so I'm not concerned about losing args/context. This seems to be one of the big blockers.

Comment: You can find all the standard properties of the `ReferenceError` class here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/ReferenceError/prototype#Properties. The name of the referenced object is not one of them.

Comment: True, only thing i guess you can do it `if(e.name==="ReferenceError"){console.log(e.message.split(" ").shift();)}`

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion! I think I'll have to give that a shot.

Comment: It's not that simple. E.g. if you try `window["foo bar"]();`

Answer (score 1):

Good question, in my knowledge (and if you check a console) there's no property/method in the ReferenceError object referring to the missing name.

You could parse the error message to extract the property name. But that'd be hard as error messages can be localized and different depending on the browser used. Although, if you want to use this for development and you control the environment, it should be fairly easy to implement with a Regexp.

Comment: Thanks. I didn't see one in the console either. I was just hopeful someone else would know something I didn't. It occurred to me that I might be able to parse it from the message, but I forgot about localization. That makes it a much bigger problem than just accounting for browser variations.